# GIMP: Applying filter from command line

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to apply filter through script or command line.
I want to add a long shadow to about 50 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basics, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560).

However LongShadow is a GEGL filter, and executing GEGL filters from scripts is still a bit of a dark art, see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Scripting-GEGL-operations?pid=18555#pid18555) for hints.

Comment: Thank you so much! As suggested in the thread, I ran gegl filter from command line, no need to even open GIMP :)